# Как сразу после запуска сервера обратиться к сервлету?

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet

Делаю начальную страницу на JSP и наткнулся на такую проблему:

- Запускаю сервер
- Жду деплой
- Открывается Index.jsp
- До этого момента все хорошо, ***НООО....***

Он не открывается по причине того, что я загружаю список из БД, подключенному к одному классу, которая обрабатывает мои данные, и выходит такая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Дело в том, что он после открытия не подключается к сервлету, не узнает что вообще там такое происходит, не знает что такое `points.size(); points.get();`.

Но стоит мне написать  `localhost:8080/user`,  то есть вызвать сервлет:

```
public class UserServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/joker";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        String message = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM joker.point;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Point p = new Point();
                p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                p.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                points.add(p);
            }
            if (rs.next()) {
                message = rs.getString(1);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            message = ex.getMessage();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                message = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        String page;
        try {
            page = request.getParameter("page");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            page = "home";
        }
        request.setAttribute("points", points);
        request.setAttribute("page", page);
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        if (page != null) {
            switch (page) {
                case "about":
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/about.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
                case "contact":
                   request.getRequestDispatcher("/contact.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Если я вызову этот сервлет, то всё заработает.

JSP файл:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="model.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.Iterator"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Joker</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.println("Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
        ArrayList<Point> points = (ArrayList<Point>) request.getAttribute("points");
    %>
    <%@ include file="_menu.jsp" %>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Home</h1>
            <p>${page}</p>
            <p>${message}</p> 
            <ul>
                <% for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) { %>
                <li>
                    <%= points.get(i).getId() %>
                    :
                    <%= points.get(i).getName() %>
                </li>
                <%}%>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы мой *"супер сайт"* при открытии сразу обращался к сервлету?

Или есть альтернативные методы?

Comment: Мне ещё не нравится отображение данных в вашем _.jsp_-файле. Независимо от того, поможет ли кто-нибудь вам исправить ошибку или нет, посмотрите на JSTL или что-либо подобное.

Comment: @Regent вот я вставил коды) Все работает только если написать LOCALHOST:8080/USER, то есть после того как обратиться к сервлету, если работаете с сервлетами и вы мастер, то подскажите как сделать чтоб после деплоя он сразу обратился к сервлету? P.S: Я не девелопер, я только учусь осваивать JavaEE)

Comment: А как, кстати, не работает? То есть что нужно написать в браузере, чтобы появилась 500-я ошибка (какой адрес отображается в браузере при деплое)? Нет, я не мастер сервлетов: всего лишь один небольшой проект делал.

Comment: В _WEB-INF/web.xml_, кстати, есть `<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>адрес</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>`.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное поздно отвечаю, но все же.

Если Вам, перед тем как отобразить страницу, нужно подгрузить данные из БД, то **первым нужно запустить контроллер (сервлет)**, который загрузит эти данные, поместит их в атрибуты запроса и "делегирует" отправку запроса нужной странице с помощью `RequestDispatcher`.

Для того чтобы **гарантировать**, что пользователь не сможет открыть страницу напрямую, можно разместить страницу в папке *WEB-INF*. Все страницы в данной папке (и любой подпапке) не будут доступны пользователю (даже если он введет верным к ней путь `/RootDir/WEB-INF/page.jsp` - сервер вернет 404).

Если Вам нужно загрузить данные один раз сразу после развертывания Вашего приложения, то можно воспользоваться **слушателями событий (listeners)**. *Java Servlet spec* определяет следующие слушатели:

- **ServletContextListener**
- **ServletContextAttributeListener**
- **HttpSessionListener**
- **HttpSessionActivationListener**
- **HttpSessionAttributeListener**
- **HttpSessionAttributeListener**
- **ServletRequestListener**
- **ServletRequestAttributeListener**

В данном случае Вам нужен *ServletContextListener* - слушает события создания и разрушения *ServletContext*:

```
public class YourListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext ctx = event.getServletContext();
        /* 
           1. Соединяетесь с базой данных
           2. Достаете данные
           3. Кладете их в качестве атрибутов ServletContext: ctx.setAttribute("attributeName", attributeValue)
        */
    }
    @Override public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: Да ладно, почему поздно, подумаешь два года прошло :) Хотя ответ всё равно лишним не будет (если он правильный), если кто-то другой с аналогичной проблемой на этот вопрос наткнётся.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Хахах)) Блин, скажу честно, я не знаю правильный ответ или нет, я даже не помню нашёл ли я ответ на него) Я уже забыл и забил на JSP) :) Но парню спасибо, напомнил мне моё прошлое, мои первые начинания)))

Comment: @E1mir, ;))))))